# Multiple file upload by webform

Tags: webforms

There are two modules for this: one needs [webform 4.x version](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (I can't update it because this gives me a lot of errors on actual website) and second doesn't work.

I tried to apply html5 attribute *multiple* to input (file type) by `template.php` and *jQuery*, but after sending form attachments links in e-mail track me to strange paths (`404 error`).

Is any possible way to print in form multifile upload field?